# Solving the differential equation $−3xdx+(x^2y+3y)dy=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

> Solve the following differential equation by finding an appropriate integrating factor
>   $$ −3x\,\mathrm{d}x+(x^2y+3y)\,\mathrm{d}y=0$$

**My attempt**:

The equation is the same as: $$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{3x}{(x+3)y}$$

Make y=z^{1/2}

Then $$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{1}{2}z^{-1/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{3x}{x^2+3}y^{-1}$$

replace y with $$y=z^{1/2}

$$\frac{1}{2}z^{-1/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{3x}{x^2+3}z^{-1/2}$$
$$
z=3\ln(x^2+3)+C, \quad \text{ while } \quad y=z^{1/2}
$$
so
$$
y^2-3\ln(x^2+3)=c
$$

screenshot is here:
[image: ![screenshot for question and my answer]

> the assignment system said my attemp was wrong without giving the correct answer. Please let me know where I am wrong. thanks a lot!

thanks for the help guys. it turns to be a bug of the website.

Comment: Please enter all the relevant information within the body of the question. It is unclear what you’re asking.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: I have tried to improve the readability of your question by introducing [$\LaTeX$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/).  It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question. Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help

Comment: It is unclear how you came to the first step. Could you elaborate? (Possibly you have a typo?)

Comment: $$\frac1y=\frac1{z^{1/2}}=z^{-1/2}$$ That's why I made my last edit.

Comment: dont know why i cannot edit the question anymore @Brian

Comment: What is the thing that you are asking in this question ?

Comment: i just want to know why my attempt is incorrect

Comment: The question appears to ask specifically for the use of integrating factors, which you have neglected. That might be the issue, if you are expected to show your steps.

Comment: it is an excercise on webwork, where the anser area is like ______________=constant, and i should fill in the blank. how do I show the integrating factor like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$−3x\,\mathrm{d}x+(x^2y+3y)\,\mathrm{d}y=0$$
$$−3x\,\mathrm{d}x+(x^2+3)y\,\mathrm{d}y=0$$
$$−3\frac {x}{(x^2+3)}\,\mathrm{d}x+y\,\mathrm{d}y=0$$
$$−\frac 32\frac {2x}{(x^2+3)}\,\mathrm{d}x+\frac 12 {d}y^2=0$$
$$−\frac 32\,\mathrm{d}\ln |{(x^2+3)}|+\frac 12 {d}y^2=0$$
Integrate:
$$− 3\ln |{(x^2+3)}|+ y^2=C$$
Therefore:
$$\boxed {y^2− 3\ln {(x^2+3)}=C}$$
Your answer seems correct to me. Maybe the webpage is expecting another form for the solution.Did you try to type the absolute value for the $\ln$ function ? Maybe it's just a formatting question. Try:
$$− 3\ln |x^2+3|+ y^2=C$$

Comment: still doesnt work. thanks for your help though

Comment: @HongmoLiu sorry then. i thought it could be that. Or a  formatting problem.

Comment: Did you try $-y^2+3\ln |x^2+3|=C $ @HongmoLiu

Comment: yes i did. did not work

Comment: lol @HongmoLiu  it seems that in  artificial intelligence there is more artificial than intelligence.

Comment: lmao i would not call this homework site artificial intellegence. more like in aretificial retard there is more artificial retard

Answer (score 2):

$-3xdx+(x^2+3y)dy=0$ is equivalent to $(x^2y+3y)dy=3xdx$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{3x}{(x^2+3)y}$$
By letting $y=\sqrt z$, we get,
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dz}{2\sqrt zdx}=\frac {3x}{(x^2+3)\sqrt z}$$

$${dz}=\frac{6x\cdot dx}{x^2+3}$$

Integrate both side, for the RHS we can use $u$-substitution with $u=x^2+3$.

$$y^2=z=3\ln(x^2+3)+C$$

$$y^2-3\ln(x^2+3)=C$$

There are $1\over 2$ that you forget to multiply with before you integrate $dz$.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i actually redid the problem and got the new answer. still incorrect by webwork

Comment: please check the screenshot, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The equation is separable, you can rewrite it as 
$$
yy'=\frac{3x}{x^2+3}.
$$
Integrating you get (via the substitution $v=x^2+3$), 
$$
\frac{y^2}2=\frac32\,\ln(x^2+3)+c.
$$
After multiplying by $2$ and renaming $c$ you get 
$$
y^2=3\ln(x^2+3)+c.
$$
So your answer is correct. The "integrating factor" thing means probably that they want you to force the equation to be exact by multiplying by an appropriate function. Not that it changes the answer.

Comment: thanks for your help. guess i'll just have to give up the points of this question